# When Should you Write a link in JS than in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, web

I was wondering if it's better to setup up writing links via JavaScript, or simple write it in your HTML page.

e.g. via JS

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");

btn.setAttribute("href", "[url]");
```

e.g. via HTML

```
<a href="[url]"></a>
```

In what context would it be better to do one over the other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
btn.setAttribute("href", "[url]");
```

this code can be used for dynamically generated HTML.

```
<a href="[url]"></a>
```

for static HTML.